# Passing a filtered list to a sibling using a React.Component style

Tags: reactjs

Got a question - the App function below has a 'filteredUsers' method that gets executed every time a pass is made - so when a search state is set it actually runs the method and its result is passed as a prop to the 'List' functional component and all is well.  How do I change this into an older style React.Component so this still works?  (as per my attempt below)

```js
const App = () => {
    const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
    const [search, setSearch] = React.useState('');

    const handleText = (event) => {
        setText(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleSearch = () => {
        setSearch(text);
    };

    console.log('*** App ***');         // each time as I type this is shown

    const filteredUsers = users.filter((user) => {
        console.log('Filter function is running ...');      // each time this is shown
        return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleText} />
            <button type="button" onClick={handleSearch}>
                Search
            </button>

            <List list={filteredUsers} />
        </div>
    );
};

const List = ({ list }) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {list.map((item) => (
                <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};

const ListItem = ({ item }) => {
    return <li>{item.name}</li>;
};
```

Then in this React.Component equivalent (App3) I am trying this:
Now how do I get a filtered list passed to the List component when I hit the search button?

```js
class App3 extends React.Component {
    state = {
        text: '',
        search: '',
    }
    handleText(event) {
        this.setState({ text: event.target.value });
    }
    handleSearch() {
        this.setState({ search: this.state.text });
    }
    filteredUsers = users.filter((user) => {
        console.log('Filter function is running ...');
        return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase());
    });
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleText.bind(this)} />
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSearch.bind(this)}>
                    Search
                </button>

                <List list={this.filteredUsers} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first version, since your component renders, the `filteredUsers` variable gets updated in every render, so you get the filtered data. You can use `useMemo` there also to make it slightly better.

In your second (class component) version, this variable is not getting updated. So, you can make it a function and invoke it to pass the `list` prop:

```
filteredUsers = () => // make function
  users.filter((user) => {
    console.log("Filter function is running ...");
    return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase());
  });

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.text}
        onChange={this.handleText.bind(this)}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSearch.bind(this)}>
        Search
      </button>

      <List list={this.filteredUsers()} /> // invoke
    </div>
  );
}
```

or you can move it into the `render` method and assign to a variable:

```
render() {
  const filteredUsers = users.filter((user) => {
    console.log("Filter function is running ...");
    return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase());
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.text}
        onChange={this.handleText.bind(this)}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSearch.bind(this)}>
        Search
      </button>

      <List list={filteredUsers} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Though, if it is not mandatory, you should go with the first version since class components are not the way to go for a new component anymore.

Here is the version with `useMemo`:

```
const filteredUsers = React.useMemo(
  () =>
    users.filter((user) => {
      console.log("Filter function is running ..."); // each time this is shown
      return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
    }),
  [search]
);
```

In this case, this variable is only evaluated when `search` changes instead of every state change.